# pull to refresh example, error

Tags: android

I'm trying to add the "pull to refresh" widget to my code, I'm just using this example:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

So, I create the pullToRefresh package, generate a jar file with eclipse and import it in other package, I got this error:

```
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.pull/example.pull.PullToRefreshExampleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.pull.widget.pullToRefresh
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.pull.widget.pullToRefresh
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at example.pull.PullToRefreshExampleActivity.onCreate(PullToRefreshExampleActivity.java:21)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  ... 11 more
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  ... 22 more
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File pulltorefresh from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f030000
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2135)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2090)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:849)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:389)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at com.pull.widget.pullToRefresh.init(pullToRefresh.java:92)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at com.pull.widget.pullToRefresh.<init>(pullToRefresh.java:66)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  ... 25 more
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: pulltorefresh
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2117)
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  ... 30 more
```

what I see more important:-

```
06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508):  at com.pull.widget.pullToRefresh.init(pullToRefresh.java:92)
```

Is this line:

```
mRefreshViewText = (TextView) mRefreshView.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_text);
```

in "pullToRefresh.java" in the package created.

From the package, what could it be happening??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you added library project into your main project?

Comment: I did, I cant understand! I found this: 06-26 10:55:05.482: E/AndroidRuntime(508): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: pulltorefresh, the file is called pullToRefresh, this is how I called it and how it exist in the jar package

Comment: Very less details provide to understand..!!

Comment: i have also recently implemented same but i dont get any error....

Comment: how did you generate the jar file? I do it with eclipse, and delete the manifest and use the "generated manifest" how did you do it?